# If $u\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{C})$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial\overline{z}}$ is a real valued nonnegative function, then $u\equiv 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

#### The problem:

If $u\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{C})$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial\overline{z}}$ is a real valued nonnegative function, then $u\equiv 0$.

#### Thoughts:

I believe this is done in the following fashion:

First, I am supposed to prove that if $u\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{C})$ and $n\geq 0$ is an integer, then
$$\iint_{\mathbb{C}}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \overline{z}}\cdot z^n \,dz\wedge d \overline{z}=0.$$

Second, I am suppose to prove, conversely, that if $f\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{C})$ and
$$\iint_{\mathbb{C}} f(z)\cdot z^n d z\wedge d \overline{z}=0$$
for all $n\geq 0$, then
$$u(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\iint_{\mathbb{C}}\frac{f(z)}{z-w} d z\wedge d \overline{z}$$ has compact support.

Finally, I believe I am supposed to use this fact to conclude and resolve my problem. I am not sure how one might achieve any of the three steps.

Comment: Why not $u=\textrm{const.}\ne 0$?

Comment: @mjw Such a function does not have compact support.

Comment: I voted to undelete this question because I do not believe that it is appropriate for a question author to delete a post after an answer has been provided.  This behaviour runs counter to the communal nature of the site, and is sometimes associated with attempt to hide cheating.

Answer (score 2):

The first proposition follows from Stokes theorem or integration by parts as $$\int_{\mathbb{C}} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \overline{z}} z^n\,dz \wedge \,d\overline{z} = - \int_{\mathbb{C}} u \frac{\partial }{\partial \overline{z}} (z^n)\,dz \wedge \,d\overline{z} = 0.$$

The second one follows from observing that if $\text{supp} (f) \subset B_R(0)$ then for $|w| > R$ we have \begin{align*} u(w) = \int_{\mathbb{C}} \frac{f(z)}{z-w}\,dz \wedge \,d\overline{z} &= -\frac{1}{w} \int_{\mathbb{C}} \frac{f(z)}{1 - (z/w)}\,dz \wedge \,d\overline{z} \\&= -\frac{1}{w}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{w^n}\int_{\mathbb{C}} f(z)z^n\,dz \wedge \,d\overline{z} = 0.\end{align*}

Combined these two propositions say that the solution to $\overline{\partial_z} u = f$ for $f \in C_c^{\infty} (\mathbb{C})$ has compact support iff $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{C}} f(z)z^n \,dz \wedge \,d\overline{z} = 0, \, \forall n \ge 0$.

Now, suppose $\overline{\partial_z} u = f \ge 0$ (real valued and positive) then $\partial_z \overline{u} = \overline{\overline{\partial_z} u} = \overline{f} = f = \overline{\partial}_z u$. Therefore, using integration by parts we have $$0 = \int_{\mathbb{C}} (\overline{\partial_z} u) z^n\,dz \wedge \,d\overline{z} = \int_{\mathbb{C}} (\partial_z \overline{u}) z^n\,dz \wedge \,d\overline{z} = -n\int_{\mathbb{C}} \overline{u} z^{n-1}\,dz \wedge \,d\overline{z},\, \forall n \ge 1.$$ That is if $v$ solves the $\overline{\partial}$-problem $$\overline{\partial_z} v = \overline{u}$$ then, $v$ is a smooth function with compact support by the equivalence established above. Furthermore, taking conjugate on both sides we note that $$\partial_z \overline{v} = u \implies \Delta \overline{v} = 4 \overline{\partial_z}\partial_z (\overline{v}) = 4\overline{\partial_z} u = 4f \ge 0.$$ That is $\overline{v}$ is a [subharmonic function with compact support and hence must be identically $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1743841/129017). This proves $u \equiv 0$.

Comment: I am having trouble following your solution to the first part. How exactly does this equality from stokes or integration by parts? I apologize; I note that I am not really familiar with stokes besides what is on the wikipedia page, and I am not really familiar with integration by parts in the sense that you appear to be using it, i.e. in the multiple variable case.

Comment: In particular, using from my knowledge of integration by parts, I am able to deduce that my desired integral is indeed what you claim in the first step, except I am left with an additional $\int uz^n dz$ term from the "$uv$" part of the integration by parts formula. Additionally, in your second step, how are you able to deduce that this is indeed zero?

Comment: The 'uv' term is integrated in the boundary of the domain. But $u$ here has compact support, thus $u$ vanishes on the boundary and the term disappers.

Comment: The support of $f$ is compact, thus the series $\frac{f(z)}{1-(z/w)} = \sum\limits_{n \ge 0} f(z)z^n/w^n$ converges uniformly on compact sets as long as $|z| < R < |w|$. Therefore we can interchange summation and integration. The given condition was $\int_\mathbb{C} f(z)z^n \,d\lambda = 0$ for all $n \ge 0$. So each term of the series is $0$.

Comment: Ah sorry, I should have been more clear. I am still referring to the first part; how do we know that this integral is $0$?

Comment: $z^n$ is holomorphic .. so $\frac{\partial }{\partial \overline{z}} (z^n) = 0$ ..

Comment: Ah, I see, by C-R. Thank you.

Comment: If I may ask yet another naive question, can't we achieve the first part of this problem via the following reasoning: since $u$ is of compact support, so is its partial, so the inner integral in the given integral evaluates to $0$ since the partial vanishes on the boundary of the domain. What error am I making here?

Comment: @lagicol that's exactly how the Stokes theorem would work here .. yes but I urge you to look at a proof of Stokes theorem to get a better feel of what's happening here. [This](https://www.math.utah.edu/~mckay/3160Cauchy.pdf) seems like a gentle introduction to the matter if you haven't seen it before.

Comment: I guess my question is whether it is even necessary to invoke that machinery. Isn't it immediately true that $\int \frac{\partial u}{\partial \overline{z}} z^n dz=0$, since the partial will vanish on the boundary of the supported domain? Then the integral in question is immediately $0$? Or is this incorrect?

Comment: You want $\int_\ell \frac{\partial u}{\partial \overline{z}} z^n\,d\overline{z} = [u(z)z^n]_{\partial \ell} - \int_{\ell} u \frac{\partial }{\partial \overline{z}} (z^n)\,d\overline{z}$ for every $z$-section $\ell$ in $\mathbb{C}$. The first term vanishes because $u$ vanishes on the boundary of $\ell$ (u has compact support) and the second vanishes as $\overline{\partial_z} (z^n) = 0$.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the careful answers to my follow-up questions. My last question is simply whether you think there is any better way to treat the third part of the problem? I don't quite believe that citing these general results about subharmonic is the intended way to go, although I am grateful to have anything at all.

Comment: @lagicol There might be :) I am not satisfied either. When I saw the sign of $f \ge 0$ I instinctively chose to use subharmonic functions (something I am more familiar with) .. Ideally I'd want to see something like $\int_{\mathbb{C}} \overline{u} \, \overline{z}^{n}\,dz \wedge \,d\overline{z} = 0,\, \forall n \ge 1$ as well so that $\overline{u}$ is now orthogonal to all polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[z,\overline{z}]$ which would conclude $u \equiv 0$ ..

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the help in any case! I think there may be a method using Theorem 1 on page 99 of Narasimhan, so I will be trying this. Please feel free to comment if you think of anything! (In fact, this would be greatly appreciated.)